# R Portfolio Analytics optimize.portfolio.rebalancing function - how to set the seed?

Tags: r, optimization, random-seed, r-portfolioanalytics

Since the optimize.portfolio.rebalancing loops through different dates, the seed for random number generation seems to be changing.  This leads to results that cannot be replicated and are inconsistent. Any advice?

I realize one can set seed outside the call to optimize.portfolio.rebalancing, but that does not work because this function recursively calls optimize.portfolio.

Hence a call such as this:

```
set.seed (1234)
optimize.portfolio.rebalancing (arg1, arg2, ..)
```

Will not give consistent results.

Comment: `set.seed(2017)` ?

Comment: Not a duplicate - added more details to the original question.  Please remove the duplicate tag.